# How to synchronize event on more than one iOS device?

Tags: ios, time

I would like to synchronize (within .05 seconds) an event in the future on more than one iOS device, whether or not those devices have network access at that future time.

To do this, I believe I'll need to sync to a common clock between these devices, and the best way would be to get a precise time from an NTP server(s). I've looked at [iOS-NTP](https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp), but the description says that that it determines time with 1 second accuracy, and that doesn't quite do it for me.

One alternative is to get the (accurate?) timestamp from a GPS clock, but I'm not sure that the devices will always have the ability to get a GPS signal.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS doesn't give you low level access to the GPS hardware, so you can't use that method.

If the devices are close to each other, you can establish a peer to peer wireless connection using GameKit. That should give you around 35ms latency with bluetooth, and the latency should be consistent so you could measure it a few times to get the clocks in sync.

If they're not close together... then I would setup a server and use that as the "real" time. With several calls you should be able to measure the latency between the device and the server, then calculate the clock offset with reasonable accuracy.

If possible use UDP instead of TCP, that way network congestion will drop packets instead of delaying them.

You'll need to keep on re-calculating the offset though, since iOS devices change their clock frequently (I think it's part of the 3G/LTE network protocol? Jumping from one cell tower to another might update the clock).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't use GameKit because there may be many devices and likely not within Bluetooth range. However, I like the idea of using a single server as the source for time, even if it's not an NTP server. I found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristian%27s_algorithm which describes such a method. I'm interested to know how often an iOS device updates its clock. I thought it was twice per week or so, but you seem to think it's more frequent.

Comment: @ScottyB I don't know how often it updates. Definitely if you cross state boundaries it will update your timezone within minutes. I don't know, but I assume it will also update the clock at the same time. I don't know. It's generally safe to assume the clock is pretty accurate, unless the user has messed with default settings.